# sqrtm() function returns nan

Tags: python, scipy

I have a `512 x 512` matrix `Avg` and it has many zero and non-zero values. Now I want an inplace element-wise square root of the matrix. This is part of my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm

Avg = sqrtm(Avg)
np.savetxt('Avg.txt', Avg)
```

But, the output is all `nan` and it says that the matrix is singular and may not have a square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want an element-wise square root.  That's [`np.sqrt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html), not [`scipy.linalg.sqrtm()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.sqrtm.html):

```
Avg = np.sqrt(Avg)
```